# How do I save data on a web form using Entity Framework 4?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-4

I have a web form in asp.net. I load the data on the page using EF4 and a foreach. Now it is time to save that data. What is the best way to do that using a postback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just grab the data from the form, create the entities and send them to the model. Remember to call SaveChanges then :-)

Marco